# Problem of duplicated in SSIS while using Lookup

Tags: ssis, etl

when charging fact table of my datawarehouse once using lookups, i can't re run the process because it doesn't charge them all , there are duplicated!

I mean when first charging the table , it loads them perfectly , if i re run it twice , it only brings 9886 rows instead of 10000 , how to correct this in SSIS?

i tried changing the matches but it didn't work , i deleted the table and re ran , nothing is going right!

[this is the part i am working on:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYxa0.png)

Comment: Your question isn't clear; what are you asking? A OLEDB destination *inserts* data, so if you run it twice you're going to insert that same data twice.

Comment: I also fail to see how SSMS and Python are related. If they are you need to be explicit on their relationship to the question.

Comment: @ThomA thank you for replying, i want to clarify the fact that i used a truncate query on the ods so that it doesn't duplicate, if i run twice it doesn't insert twice, but it doesn't bring alll data .

Comment: What does "charge the table" mean in this context? That's not a normal database management/development term that I've ever heard.